# Should custom exceptions be used when only a message is involved?

Tags: c#, exception

I have seen many cases where custom exceptions where created, where only the 3 standard constructor overrides are used with no extra information to it.

In those cases I recommended to use InvalidOperationException because in practice there were no callers that catch those custom exceptions.

For example for use in a default block in a switch statement:

```
public InvalidSwitchValueException()
            : base() { }

        public InvalidSwitchValueException(string message)
            : base(message) { }

        public InvalidSwitchValueException(string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException) { }
```

What would you recommend ?

Comment: It helps catch only the correct type of exception.

Comment: Often Exceptions are created to allow callers to take specific action (that would not be known if only "InvalidOperationException" is thrown.  Giving the caller a means to determine how to recover from an Exception is good design practice.  (One should avoid "application suicide" at all costs in today's modern world.)

Comment: [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has 4 standard constructors.

Comment: The type of an exception is useful information about it. You could make your custom exception derivate from `InvalidOperationException` if you want to catch it as an invalid operation too.

Comment: While I agree with the other commenters for most exceptions, `InvalidOperationException` often belongs to the group of exceptions that do not need to be handled because they should never be thrown in a stable application version (just like, for example, `ArgumentNullException`, which IMO exists solely for debugging purposes). Looking at the name of the exception from the question, this may be a comparable case.

Comment: `InvalidSwitchValueException` seems overkill. You'd just use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Resharper also says the same..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: If the value that was out of range is indeed an argument, at least.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper is onto something important here; is this an exception that should never be caught because it indicates a bug in the caller that should be fixed? If so then *design the exception to make the bug easy to find and fix*, rather than designing the exception to be *easy to catch*.

Comment: I find it beneficial to not throw exceptions at all and make checks they aren't thrown by the system (as much as that's possible), handle the few ones that are thrown at the entry point. This allows for better flow control as the application ages.

Comment: Because our code did not have any callers (catchers) to this kind of exception, it looks more like a kind of team exception. As Framework Design Guidelines states, avoid team exceptions ;-)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: indeed, ArgumentOutOfRangeException is a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Depends. If you intend to use it like this:

```
try
{
}
catch (InvalidSwitchValueException)
{
    // handle this special case differently
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

It is much neater than:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e.Message == "Check the message")
    {
        // handle this special case differently
    }
}
```

If it is just to have a different type, with no intend to catch it anywhere, it don't see the point. If you do, it will improve your code quality. Think what happens if you have multilingual error messages (like .NET itself does). **You can't and shouldn't rely on the message! Never!**

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) makes a good point in comment too:

> Is this an exception that should never be caught because it indicates a bug in the caller that should be fixed? If so then *design the exception to make the bug easy to find and fix*, rather than designing the exception to be *easy to catch*.

A very useful point in naming exceptions is that *if* they are thrown, it's easier to find them. As an example: `NullReferenceException` is the worst to get since (without the call stack) it absolutely gives you nothing to help analyze the problem. A check and throw of a typed exception like `CatDidntFindMouseException` gives you a starting point and probably a clue what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Note, be careful with checking `e.Message == "Something"` if you are working with the .NET built in exceptions. The message will be different depending on what language you have your OS set to. (But some times you have to and there is no exposed parameter you can check to look for your reqired information, I am looking at you `SqlException`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Sorry, that was an obvious one to me. Will update.

Comment: @EricLippert: I incorporated your comment in my answer. Does the added text reflect your point?